# I have got an requirement for load testing . i was given both avg. and peak TPH. also avg and peak user load

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, loadrunner, stress-testing

I have to do performance testing of an ecommerce application where i got the details needed like Avg TPH and peak TPH . also Avg User and Peak User.

for e.g., an average of 1000 orders/hour, the peak of 3000 orders/hour during the holiday season, expected to grow to 6000 orders/hour next holiday season.

I was afraid which value to be considered for current users and TPH for performing load test for an hour.
also what load will be preferable foe stress testing and scalability testing. 
It would be a great helpful not only for the test point of view but also will help me in understanding the conceptually which would help me in a great deal down the lane.

Answer (score 1):

This is a high business risk endeavor.  Get it wrong and your ledger doesn't go from red to black on the day after thanksgiving, plus you have a high probability of winding up with a bad public relations event on Twitter.   Add to that greater than 40% of people who hit a website failure will not return.

That being said, do your skills match the risk to the business.  If not, the best thing to do is to advise your management to acquire a higher skilled team.  Then you should shadow them in all of their actions.

I think it helps to have some numbers here.  There are roughly 35 days in this year's holiday shopping season.   This translates to 840 hours.

- @$25 avg sale, you are looking at revenue of $21 million
- @$50 avg sale, ...42 Million
- @100 avg sale, ...84 Million

Numbers based upon the average of 1000 sales per hour over 840 hours.

Every hour of downtime at peak costs you

- @$25 avg sale, ...$75K
- @$50 avg sale, ...$150K
- @$100 avg sale, ...$300K

Numbers based upon 3000 orders per hour at peak.  If you have downtime then greater than 40% of people will not return based upon latest studies.  And you have the Twitter affect where people complain loudly and draw off potential site visitors.

I would advise you to bring in a team.  Act fast, the really good engineers are quickly being snapped up for Holiday work.  These are not numbers to take lightly nor is it work to press someone into that hasn't done it before.

If you are seriously in need and your marketing department knows exactly how much increased conversion they get from a faster website, then I can find someone for you.  ***They will do the work upfront at no charge, but they will charge a 12 month residual based upon the decrease in response time and the increased conversion that results***

Comment: thanks james. i would like to takeup this work. may be would need your guidance how to approach.

Answer (score 0):

Normally [Performance Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/performance-testing-vs-load-testing-vs-stress-testing/) technique is not limited to only one scenario, you need to run different performance test types to assess various aspects of your application.

1. [Load Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) - which goal is to check how does your application behave under **anticipated** load, in your case it would be simulating 1000 orders per hour.
2. [Stress Testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress_testing) - putting the application under test under maximum anticipated load (in your case 3000 TPH). Another approach is gradually increasing the load until response time starts exceeding acceptable thresholds or errors start occurring (whatever comes the first) or up to 6000 TPH if you don't plan to scale up. This way you will be able to identify the [bottleneck](https://www.quora.com/What-is-bottleneck-in-performance-testing) and determine what will be the component which fails which could be in

   - lack of hardware power
   - problems with database
   - inefficient algorithms used in your application

You can also consider executing a [Soak Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soak_testing) - putting your application under prolonged load, this way you will be able to catch the majority of [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Comment: thank you @Dmitri T. it is very informative. but how should i approach for fixing the value w.r.t current users.  could you please clarifyifs the concurrent users for the load test is Avg User value or peak user value? what about the no. of current users for stress testing? let us assume Avg user is 300  and peak user on any busy day is 600